# List registered request mappings in the log at startup

Tags: spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I want to list all registered request mappings in the log at application startup (Spring MVC, log4j). Ideally I want to view two things for each entry: URL and corresponding controller's method.

What have I tried: I searched in [corresponding documentation entry](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) without success.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this blogpost for more information about how to log Spring MVC mappings in your application, [source blogpost](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/03/endpoint-documentation-controller-for.html).

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

@Controller
public class EndpointDocController {

    private final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

    @Autowired
    public EndpointDocController(RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping) {

        this.handlerMapping = handlerMapping;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpointdoc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void show(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("handlerMethods",
                this.handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From spring's code (`org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping`):

```
this.handlerMethods.put(mapping, newHandlerMethod);                        
if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {                                              
    logger.info("Mapped \"" + mapping + "\" onto " + newHandlerMethod);    
}
```

As you see the code is already there and mapped at **INFO** level ([apache-commons-logging](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2)), so you should see every `@RequestMapping` by default, no matter if they are in `@Controller` or `@RestController`.

---

**⚠** *Because you ask for it,* first make sure that a logger-implementation is available. If you see

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

At application start there is **no logger-implementation**! If this message occour, you have to decide what logger-implementation you like to use. The commonly most used are slf4j, log4j and jul.

### Slf4j / Maven

Add this to the dependencies to see your output.

```
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version> </dependency>
```

### Why not use commons-logging?

Simply its a api to be used by others, not an implementation, not a single `System.out` is made by `commons-logging`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like starting from Spring 3.1 you need to activate info logging for `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(...)`.